# Key combination for cin.eof()

Tags: c++, windows

What is the input key for `cin.eof()` as stated in this code

```
while (1) {
  int i = cin.get(); 
  if (cin.eof()) 
     break;
  ...
}
```

In linux, I know it is CTRL+D, but that key combination doesn't work in Visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> are the usual ones (with <kbd>F6</kbd> usually preferred -- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> only works dependably if preceded and followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: @mahmood: That's why I said to use F6, not ctrl+F6 (i.e., you want to use F6 by itself).

Answer (score 1):

In a DOS/Windows console it should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux/Unix, Ctrl + D sends a signal (SIGQUIT) to the controlling terminal / process. This has nothing to do with cin.eof().

You can interrupt console-applications in VS using Ctrl-C, but this kills the process.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm).